# SignalR + Win RT(Windows 8.1) + using unsigned certificate not working

Tags: windows-runtime, certificate, signalr, unsigned, self-signed

After searching for more than 4 hours, making a Win RT + SignalR work with a selfsigned certificate. Found it! So I share a solution here.
You get the error:

*The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.*

*The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.*

```
  public class DefaultHttpClientUnsigned : DefaultHttpClient
{
    protected override HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler()
    {
          var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.IncompleteChain);
        var handler = new WinRtHttpClientHandler(filter);
        return handler;
    }


}
```

Then for creating the connection:

```
var connection = new HubConnection(address);
var client = new DefaultHttpClientUnsigned();
connection.Start(client);
```

// https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRtHttpClientHandler
The source code for the WinRtHttpClientHandler  (if it's not available anymore)

```
public class WinRtHttpClientHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private static readonly Version NoVersion = new Version(0, 0);
    private static readonly Version Version10 = new Version(1, 0);
    private static readonly Version Version11 = new Version(1, 1);
    private readonly rt.HttpClient _client;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public WinRtHttpClientHandler(IHttpFilter httpFilter)
    {
        _client = new rt.HttpClient(httpFilter);
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CheckDisposed();

        var rtMessage = await ConvertHttpRequestMessaageToRt(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var resp = await _client.SendRequestAsync(rtMessage).AsTask(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var netResp = await ConvertRtResponseMessageToNet(resp, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return netResp;
    }

    internal static async Task<rt.HttpRequestMessage> ConvertHttpRequestMessaageToRt(HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var rt = new rt.HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = new rt.HttpMethod(message.Method.Method),
            Content = await GetContentFromNet(message.Content).ConfigureAwait(false),
            RequestUri = message.RequestUri,
        };

        CopyHeaders(message.Headers, rt.Headers);

        foreach (var prop in message.Properties)
            rt.Properties.Add(prop);

        return rt;
    }

    internal static async Task<HttpRequestMessage> ConvertRtRequestMessageToNet(rt.HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = new HttpMethod(message.Method.Method),
            RequestUri = message.RequestUri,
            Content = await GetNetContentFromRt(message.Content, token).ConfigureAwait(false),
        };

        foreach (var header in message.Headers)
            req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);

        foreach (var prop in message.Properties)
            req.Properties.Add(prop);

        return req;
    }

    internal static void CopyHeaders(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> source, IDictionary<string, string> destination)
    {
        var headers = from kvp in source
                      from val in kvp.Value
                      select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key, val);
        foreach (var header in headers)
            destination.Add(header);
    }

    internal static async Task<rt.IHttpContent> GetContentFromNet(HttpContent content)
    {
        if (content == null)
            return null;

        var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var c = new rt.HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());

        CopyHeaders(content.Headers, c.Headers);

        return c;
    }

    internal static async Task<HttpContent> GetNetContentFromRt(rt.IHttpContent content, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (content == null)
            return null;

        var str = await content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync().AsTask(token).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var c = new StreamContent(str.AsStreamForRead());

        foreach (var header in content.Headers)
            c.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);

        return c;
    }

    internal static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ConvertRtResponseMessageToNet(rt.HttpResponseMessage message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)(int)message.StatusCode)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = message.ReasonPhrase,
            RequestMessage = await ConvertRtRequestMessageToNet(message.RequestMessage, token).ConfigureAwait(false),
            Content = await GetNetContentFromRt(message.Content, token).ConfigureAwait(false),
            Version = GetVersionFromEnum(message.Version),
        };

        foreach (var header in message.Headers)
            resp.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);

        return resp;
    }

    internal static Version GetVersionFromEnum(rt.HttpVersion version)
    {
        switch (version)
        {
            case rt.HttpVersion.None:
                return NoVersion;
                break;
            case rt.HttpVersion.Http10:
                return Version10;
                break;
            case rt.HttpVersion.Http11:
                return Version11;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("version");
        }
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("WinRtHttpClientHandler");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !_disposed)
        {
            _client.Dispose();

            _disposed = true;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps some people out there.